# Who cleans up the space junk?

Tags: star-wars

All the junk that floats in space above planets like Coruscant, old satellites, garbage, destroyed starfighters, metals, etc. Do they clean that stuff up with special craft? I checked Wookieepedia and I came up with nothing.

Comment: Why would it need to be cleaned up?  Space is BIG after all.

Comment: My guess: R2-D2 had a spare day.

Comment: There are probably space junk scavenger (space jawas?)

Comment: Probably specialized garbage men stationed in space. Also known as spaced junkies.

Comment: Plot twist: WALL-E does it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Star-Wars has shield technology.  There is no need to clean up space junk.  Shield = no risk of damage from impact of junk in orbit.

Eventually it all comes down and burns up (or crashes), so gravity cleans up orbital junk.

There are several questions on [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debris) about problems we have.  For the most part these are not issues in the Star Wars universe.

Comment: I don't think shields are a complete answer to the space debris problem. There is already enough debris orbiting the Earth to cause non-negligible problems for our satellites and spacecraft; there would be tons of debris generated around a planet like Coruscant. The debris impact frequency on satellites would be extremely high, and shields require energy and maintenance. Also, [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/1007/269) on Space indicates that space debris can hang around a long time.

Comment: NASA's [orbital debris FAQ] says the average debris in low orbit is traveling at 8km/s.  That means that for a 1kg piece of space junk, the [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) is on the order of 30 million Joules, or about 8kg [TNT equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent).  I'd think having to fly through a field of that would be taxing on a ship or satellite's shields.

Comment: @matts In the first *Star Wars* movie, *Millennium Falcon* came out of hyperspace into the middle of the remnants of a recently exploded *planet*.  If that kind of debris field wasn't a problem for their shield technology, wrecked spacecraft and little flecks of paint aren't worth cleaning up.

Comment: Not every ship has shields.

Answer (score 6):

There are two races who specialize in garbage collection, according to published  sources.

The bad garbage guys are the Ugors, soupy, space-armored religious fanatics who are the SW equivalent of hoarders. They have an entire stellar system which they run as a junkyard/religious shrine. Customers can pay to "make a pilgrimage" and search through the debris for their desires.

The good guys are the schnauser-like, super-recycling Squibs, whose wheeler-dealing culture has been featured in several works. They love to make complicated bargains which wind up making everyone feel like they got away with a great deal.

These two races appeared first in "Scavenger Hunt: An Adventure for Star Wars the Roleplaying Game" by Brad Freeman, published by West End Games (1989). Squibs have appeared subsequently in several works, usually as comic relief.

See also http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Squib for a complete bibliography.

Comment: There are also scavengers who make money by collecting salvage of derelict craft.